# What is keyboard shortcut combination for ResourceFunction?

Tags: notebooks, keyboard, resourcefunction

I have seen in some notebooks that functions called with [`ResourceFunction["PairwiseScatterPlot"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PairwiseScatterPlot)
appear with a red set of square brackets enclosing a red filled square. It would be great to know the shortcut instead of having to type out ResourceFunction every time. Any help is appreciated. [image]

Comment: I don't think there is one. This is a display form, not a form one types in manually.

Comment: Perhaps `ResourceFunctionInput` over at the function repository will do what you are asking:  https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ResourceFunctionInput

Comment: (+1) Mostly for the pointing out [`PairwiseScatterPlot`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PairwiseScatterPlot).

Comment: @JoshuaSchrier that’s it for sure, you should post it as an answer so that OP can accept it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ResourceFunctionInput](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ResourceFunctionInput) (over at the Wolfram Function Repository) achieves this goal.

As described in its documentation:

`ResourceFunction["ResourceFunctionInput"]["InstallAlias"]`

permanently adds an interactive input for ResourceFunction symbols as input alias `esc-rfi-esc` that allows for inline creation of `ResourceFunction` symbols.  There are also other options for adding menu bar items and other ways to use this functionality.

Comment: This needs to become built-in.

Comment: Not sure why but on my machine (Ubuntu 18.08 with MMA 12.0) this fails with the message ```System`PacletUninstall::shdw: Symbol PacletUninstall appears in multiple contexts {System`, PacletManager`}; definitions in context System` may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions.```

Anyone having the same experience?

Comment: For the record, upgrading to MMA 12.2 fixed the issue.